# MS Access using VBA and Form, build a query string and run it

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a MS Access form where it will ask users to select or type in words that will be used in the `where` clause for the query.

When the button is clicked, it will build the string and use that to run the query. This will be a read only and to view the subset results from a link table in SQL Server. Nothing more. I tried it with `DoCmd.RunSQL` but that is only for action type like update, delete, etc.

On click button event, it will have similar query.

```
strSQL = "Select top 10 * Where ID = ''" + textbox1.value + "'' from linked_Table_Name;"
```

This did not work.

`DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, and most importantly, **never concatenate user-obtained data as part of a SQL statement**. Any application which uses this technique is wide open to a [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attack and will also fail if the user includes a string delimiter (such as a single quote) or other reserved character in the input they provide.

Instead, use parameters.

For your scenario, I might suggest creating a saved query with the SQL:

```
select top 10 t.*
from linked_Table_Name t
where t.ID = Forms![Your Form Name]![textbox1]
```

Where `Your Form Name` is the name of your form containing the control `textbox1`.

Then, your on-click event can simply call the [`OpenQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery) method of the [`DoCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd) object:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourSavedQuery"
```